# Google Sheets to Calendar not adjusting for DST

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

So, I am running into an issue with google calendar. Any events added to my calendar via my Google Sheets script do not properly adjust after DST. Not entirely sure if there is a solution.

For example: Work is set for 10AM prior to DST. After DST it's now set for 11AM.

Below is the current script I am using to add the dates/times to calendar.

```
function CalendarTest() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var calendarId = "*******";
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
var lastRow = spreadsheet.getRange("L61:M62").getValues();

for (x=0; x<lastRow.length; x++){

  var shift = lastRow[x];

var startTime = shift[0];
var endTime = shift[1];

eventCal.createEvent("Work", new Date(startTime), new Date(endTime));


}// End of for Loop

}// End of CalendarTest Function
```

Below is my current spreadsheet setup. I can easily and paste from the website to the top left cell and have it convert it to the right columns.

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGK0J.png)

Answer (score 0):

You always can adjust your time with the next snippet:

add 1 hour to your time:

`date.setHours((date.getHours()+1))`

for example:

```
function changeDate(){

  // [20-03-11 15:03:06:229 UTC] Wed Mar 11 15:03:06 GMT+00:00 2020 
  let date = new Date();

  // add 1 hour to your current date
  // [20-03-11 15:03:06:233 UTC] Wed Mar 11 16:03:06 GMT+00:00 2020
  date.setHours((date.getHours()+1)) 

}
```

Works with Apps Script

**Reference:**

- [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: The script only adds the events to the calendar it wouldn't change already created events. I assume that if I add them post DST, it'll have them at the correct time. I was wondering if I could get it to somehow play nice with DST.